# How can I properly group user defined variables for syntax highlighting?

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I'm trying to capture user defined variables for highlighting purposes. I've been wrestling with this for a while and finally have something that appears to work (at least on various regex debugging sites.) However, when I throw it into Ace Editor, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /#<error>/: Unterminated group
```

Here is my regex, and the example I'm trying to parse.

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:volatile|non_volatile|persistent)\s*(?:integer|char|long|slong)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:$|.*|\[)|\s*(?:integer|char|long)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:$|.*|\[)|\s*(?!volatile|persistent|non_volatile|define_variable)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:$|.*|\[)))|(?:volatile|non_volatile|persistent)\s([a-zA-Z0-9]*))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cPxCGjzarXDFAvDf)

```
define_variable
volatile integer loop;
volatile char someChar
volatile long someLong
volatile anotherChar[3] = 'ABC';
anInteger = 33
VOLATILE INTEGER yetAnotherInt
Volatile[32] // this is not valid
someCharArray[32]
char anotherCharArray[32]
char singleChar
persistent slong slongValue[32];
```

Testing my regex & code example on regex101.com yields the proper matches - ideas, pointers, suggestions?

Comment: There is an unwritten law, if your regex is so long it doesn't fit on the screen, break it down into multiple smaller ones, and do the operation step by step or you are going to have a bad time debugging.

Comment: @Winchestro - I agree and would say it's not limited to regex. ;)

I just don't think Ace can accept broken regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule regexps for ace either need to not have capturing groups or have a row of groups spanning whole text (like `/(foo)(\s+)(bar)(\s+)(baz)/`).

The main issue here is that your regexp is too complex, You don't have to put everything into one rule but every time you have `|` at the root level create a new rule, and let ace combine them.

something like

```
   {
      regex: /(volatile|non_volatile|persistent)(\s+)(integer|char|long|slong)(\s+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
      token: ["token1", "text", "token2", "text", "token3"]
   },
   {
      regex: /(\s*)(integer|char|long)(\s+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
      token: ["text", "token1", "text", "token2"]
   },
```

even better would be to use `createKeywordMapper` see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.3/lib/ace/mode/javascript_highlight_rules.js#L40

Also note that using `\s*` instead of `\s+` in `(?:volatile|non_volatile|persistent)\s*(?:integer|char|long|slong)` matches `volatileinteger` which is likely wrong.